# Java - EnumSet.add(enum), throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, enums, nullpointerexception, enumset

This is in Java, cross platform and being debugged on a computer running Ubuntu Oneric with OpenJDK installed as my runtime.

I have an EnumSet for checking inside of in a class in a game I'm working on. I have this readout from logcat, from debug aplenty in my constructor:

```
Tile : passability being set...?
Exception in thread "Thread-1" javax.media.opengl.GLException:java.lang.NullPointerException
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.darkglass.map.Tile.addPassability(Tile.java:144)
    ...
```

Not amusing. Tracking it down, my problem seems to be, entirely, this line:

```
public void addPassability(Passability type)
{
    this.passability.add(type);
}
```

By which I mean the body of that function. It is called from the constructor as:

```
this.addPassability(Passability.AIR);
```

When the NullPointerException happens. In the body of the Passability Enum Type, I have

```
public enum Passability
{
    AIR, ALL, GROUND, NONE, SIGHT, SKILL, STRUCTURE, WATER;
}
```

as, quite literally, the entire enum save package declaration. this.passability is declared

```
private EnumSet <Passability> passability;
```

at the beginning of the class definition and I was under the impression that the add() method was inherited as part of the definition of EnumSet in the Java Standard.

I'm self-taught, but I'm not crazy. Either I've got something wrong or there's a better way to do this. Anyone with some useful knowledge out there able to lend a hand?

Comment: could you show more chunks of your code. All I see if a line here and there.

Comment: Jon Skeet has it.

I never initialized it because I'm so used to only using primitives ~ I try to KISS my work because it keeps things sane.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So you've *declared* the `passability` variable, but you've shown no sign of it being assigned a value other than the default value of `null`. Perhaps you meant:

```
private EnumSet<Passability> passability = EnumSet.noneOf(Passability.class);
```

An `EnumSet` is an object, like any other - so unless you explicitly give your variable, it will have the default value of `null` and when you call `add` on it, you'll get a `NullPointerException` - which is exactly what's happened here.

Comment: Yes sir, that works just fine. However, I have some concern on that note. Right now, that's added to the field declaration ~ is it _really_ safe there, or should I move it down to my constructor call?

That is,

`private EnumSet<Passability> passability;`

up above and

`this.passability = EnumSet.noneOf(Passability.class);`

in the body of the constructor?

Comment: @ThatGuy: It's fine. They're pretty much equivalent.